# Harmonic oscillator with time dependent friction term

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

Suppose I have a harmonic oscillator of the following form:

$\ddot x(t)=-F(t)\dot x(t)-x(t), F(t)>0$ for all $t$.

From the physical perspective, the term proportional to $\dot x(t)$ represents a friction term. Hence, if $F(t)>0$ for all $t$, I would expect that $\lim_{t\to\infty} x(t)=0$. But I am not sure how to proof that, and perhaps it is not even true, and my thinking is too simplistic.

If someone had some thoughts, I would appreciate! : )

EDIT: I can probably also assume $F(t)$ to be $C^\infty$.

Comment: I suppose that $F$ is time depending and since this come from physics i suspect that $F$ is $C^{\infty}$

Comment: It is time dependent, yes. And it most certainly $C^\infty$. I don't know too much concrete things about $F$ though. But if I could show something with the assumptions $F(t)>0$ and $C^\infty$ that would be already a good start, if not sufficient for my purposes.

Comment: That's interesting! Could you perhaps elaborate on why this is? It is not obvious to me.

Comment: @Chip This sounds like something I should try! (Would also be a chance for me to warm up some complex analysis ; ).) One question to the condition that $F(t)$ should be finite at infinity: Here you mean $t\to\infty$ (not $u\to\infty$), right?

Comment: @Winther Thanks a lot for clarifying! I can see where you are coming from.

Comment: Your problem is thoroughly analyzed in Cabot $\it{et \; al.}$, TRANSACTIONS OF THE AMERICAN MATHEMATICAL SOCIETY Volume 361, Number 11, November 2009, Pages 5983–6017. I added some details from the paper in a comment to the answer below.

Comment: @Chip Thanks a lot for the hint! I will have a look at that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will show that as long as $F(t) \geq 0$ and $\int_0^\infty F(t){\rm d}t < \infty$ then we won't have $\lim_{x\to \infty}x(t) = 0$ unless $x\equiv 0$.

Consider the energy of the oscillator, $E(t) = x^2(t) + x'^2(t)$. Using the ODE this  is found to satisfy
$$E'(t) = -2F(t)x'^2(t) \geq -2F(t) E(t)$$
Since the energy is decreasing and bounded below by $0$ it will have a finite limit $E_\infty$ as $t\to\infty$. Thus the system will always settle into a circle $x^2 + x'^2 = E_\infty$ in the $(x,x')$ phase-space asymptotically and $x\to 0$ is the case only if $E_\infty = 0$. Integrating the inequality above we obtain
$$E_\infty \geq E(0) e^{-2\int_0^\infty F(t){\rm d}t}$$
which is strictly positive as long as the integral in the exponential is finite and $x\not\equiv 0$. I also suspect the converse, if this integral is infinite then the limit will be zero, could be true.

Comment: For keeping consistency with physical definition, I point out that the total 'energy of the oscillator' (ie, the sum of the kinetic and potential energies) reads: $E(t) = x'^2(t)/2 + x(t)^2/2$.

Comment: I did some numerical simulations and they seem to confirm that if $\int_0^\infty F(t) dt$ is finite, in the $(x(t), v=x'(t))$ plane the motion approaches a limit circle that does not include $(0,0)$.

Comment: Cabot et al. TRANS. AM. MATH. SOC. vol 361, 11, Nov 2009, pag. 5983–6017 gives lower and upper bounds for the energy and a detailed analysis. Interestingly, eg, for $F(t)=c/(t+1)$ one has $k/t^c \le x(t)^2+x'(t)^2 \le K/t^c$, with $k,K$ strictly positive, finite. In general, is intriguing that there is a lower ($k$ constant) / upper ($K$ constant) bound (with $F(t)$ under mild conditions given in Prop. 3.4 in paper) of the form $k e^{-\int_0^t F(s) ds}$ / $K e^{-\int_0^t F(s) ds}$, respectively. ($F, \dot F$ must go to $0$ and $\ddot F + \dot F F $ must have constant sign at $\infty$.)

Comment: (continue from above): (Example 3.2 in the paper) for $F(t)=1/(1+t)^\alpha$ and $0 \lt \alpha \lt 1$, the upper and lower bounds are proportional to $e^{-t^{1-\alpha}/(1-\alpha)}$